# How to use a jQuery code using JavaScript if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

So I have these two very familiar jQuery code (fade in & out animation), however I want either one of those code to only work if it is required using an if/else statement.

I am aware there is no if/else statement for jQuery, but is there a way you can use JavaScript to call on a jQuery code using the if/else statement?

Here is what I want to do:
I have a game, which attacks if a button is clicked, JavaScript runs an if/else statement and runs the `Math.floor(Math.random()` code.  With a selection of numbers split into the if/else statement. When a condition is true in the if/else statement, a string will be printed(you won, or lost or a draw). 
But I also want a jQuery code to run, where an image fades in and out quickly. How do I do that?

```js
function selectChanged() {
  attacks = document.getElementById("hits");
  if (attacks.value == "not_valid") {
    document.getElementById("battle").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("battle").disabled = false;
  }
}

function vvBattle() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("hits").value;
  var updatedSelection = selection.replace(/_/g, ' ');
  var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

  if (youHit >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You hit the bad guy with " + updatedSelection + " and won!";
  } else if (youHit > 5) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You nearly had it, but it wasn't enough, he's retreated!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "Your attack was too weak, you lost!";
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gamePic").hide();
  $(".submit_button").click(function() {
    $(".gamePic").fadeIn('slow');
    $(".gamePic").fadeOut('slow');
  });
});       //I want the above JQ to execute when the condition "if" is true and the code below if "else is true.

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".badGuy").hide();
  $(".submit_button").click(function() {
    $(".badGuy").fadeIn('slow');
    $(".badGuy").fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <select name="hits" id="hits" value="Select" onchange="selectChanged()">
      <option value="not_valid">-- select an option --</option>
      <option value="attack1">attack1</option>
      <option value="attack2">attack2</option>
      <option value="attack3">attack3</option>
      <option value="attack4">attack4</option>
      <option value="attack5">attack5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="submit_button" id="battle" onclick="vvBattle()" value="Battle" disabled="disabled">
  </form>
  <p id="dragonGame" class="game1SectionGreen"></p>
</div>

<img class="gamePic" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/b/b5/Master-chief-20070918004603376.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131205015213" />
<img class="badGuy" src="http://i1323.photobucket.com/albums/u599/slikezadesktop/bad-guy-avengers-movie-wallpapers.jpg" />
```

My jQuery code isn't working here, not sure why, works on notepad ++.

Comment: You can look into `fadeToggle()`

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `I am aware there is no if/else statement for jQuery` jQuery code ***is*** Javascript. jQuery is just a library, therefore there is *always* an if/else statement you can use. The only reason the image fades in/out quickly is because you are telling it to. If you want to delay the fadeOut, simply use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

First off, jQuery is just javascript. it is library of functions written in JS to give you more functionality and out of the box options. there is no difference between "JS code" and "jQuery code", they are one and the same. It would be like saying your `selectChanged` function is its own code, different from javascript code.

Secondly, you don't have to surround every jQuery statement with a `$('document').ready()`. Just wrap all your code in one of these if you are worried about the DOM loading before your code runs.

With these two things in mind, all you have to do is put your jQuery code inside of the if statements:

```
if (youHit >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You hit the bad guy with " + updatedSelection + " and won!";
    $(".gamePic").hide();
    $(".gamePic").fadeIn('slow');
    $(".gamePic").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

The same goes for whatever you want the else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute classname based on your condition and then use it to toggle them.

Following is a sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gamePic").hide();
  $(".badGuy").hide();
  $(".submit_button").click(function() {

    var el = ({{if condition here}}) ? ".gamePic": ".badGuy";

    $(el).fadeIn('slow');
    $(el).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

**Note:** You should not have multiple `$(document).ready()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<title>Try</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
 function selectChanged() {
  attacks = document.getElementById("hits");
  if (attacks.value == "not_valid") {
    document.getElementById("battle").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("battle").disabled = false;
  }
}

function vvBattle() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("hits").value;
  var updatedSelection = selection.replace(/_/g, ' ');
  var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

  if (youHit >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You hit the bad guy with " + updatedSelection + " and won!";
     $(".gamePic").show();
  $(".submit_button").click(function() { 
    $(".gamePic").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
});

  } else if (youHit > 5) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You nearly had it, but it wasn't enough, he's retreated!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "Your attack was too weak, you lost!";
    $(".badGuy").show();
  $(".submit_button").click(function() { 
   $(".badGuy").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
   });
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".gamePic").hide();
  $(".badGuy").hide();
});     
</script>

   <div id="form">
  <form>
    <select name="hits" id="hits" value="Select" onchange="selectChanged()">
      <option value="not_valid">-- select an option --</option>
      <option value="attack1">attack1</option>
      <option value="attack2">attack2</option>
      <option value="attack3">attack3</option>
      <option value="attack4">attack4</option>
      <option value="attack5">attack5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="submit_button" id="battle" onclick="vvBattle()" value="Battle" disabled="disabled">
  </form>
  <p id="dragonGame" class="game1SectionGreen"></p>
</div>

<img class="gamePic" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/b/b5/Master-chief-20070918004603376.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131205015213" />
<img class="badGuy" src="http://i1323.photobucket.com/albums/u599/slikezadesktop/bad-guy-avengers-movie-wallpapers.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, jQuery is Javascript!

First thing you want to do is turn each of those into their own function:

```
function flashGamePic() {
  $(".gamePic").fadeIn('slow');
  $(".gamePic").fadeOut('slow');
}

function flashBadGuy() {
  $(".badGuy").fadeIn('slow');
  $(".badGuy").fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Then call the function wherever you want in your if/else statement:

```
  if (youHit >= 8) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You hit the bad guy with " + updatedSelection + " and won!";
    flashGamePic();
  } else if (youHit > 5) {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "You nearly had it, but it wasn't enough, he's retreated!";
    flashGamePic();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dragonGame").innerHTML = "Your attack was too weak, you lost!";
    flashBadGuy();
  }
```

Here's a demo of it all put together:
http://codepen.io/JeffreyPia/pen/qNbqjX

Comment: Your first funtion should fade out *after* fading in. Thats not what it currently does!